# Magento 2: How to fetch a custom attribute of products

Tags: magento2, rest-api, custom-attributes

I am trying to fetch a custom attribute which is of collection type.

I need to get all various types of collection in that attribute using Magento 2 custom rest API and display them in postman.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a **GET** to -

```
/rest/V1/products/*SKU*/options/
```

It will display the product options.

You can narrow it down a particular option by doing -

```
/rest/V1/products/*SKU*/options/*OPTION_ID*
```

Found in the [Swagger documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html).

Comment: I want to get values for all the products not for a particular sku